# Plot of a mixed signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following signal

```
xa=4000.*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+1000.*sin(2*pi*f2*t)+ 500.*sin(2*pi*f3*t);
```

and the values of `f1,f2 and f3` are

```
f1=50000;
f2=500000;
f3=2500000;
```

and with the above information I have to find a figure like [image]
in MATLAB. I am using the following code but not getting a figure like this.

```
close all;
clc;
%subplot(2,1,1)
t=0:0.0005:1;
f1=50000;
f2=500000;
f3=2500000;
xa=4000.*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+1000.*sin(2*pi*f2*t)+ 500.*sin(2*pi*f3*t);
% xa=cos(2*pi*f*t);
plot(t,xa)
```

I also tried with the different time intervals `t` but not getting the required figure.

---

Comment: What does your plot look like? I think your t interval is WAY off. The time span in the plot is 100us. Try with t=0:0.00000005:0.0001 or something like that.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen Yes you are right. I tried it and it worked. Why don't you post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your plot look like? I think your t interval is WAY off. The time span in the plot is 100us. Try with t=0:0.00000005:0.0001 or something like that

Comment: thank you, it worked, but how did you find the range of t like  t=0:0.00000005:0.0001, can you tell me the calculation behind it

Comment: @TuhinDas Your sample rate was WAY below the Nyquist frequency of any of the sinusoids and your time span was 50000 cycles of f1 versus 5 as Peter suggests.

Comment: t=0:0.00000005:0.0001, how come Nyquist interval become 0.00000005, because according to the formulation Nyquist interval is T=1/2fm, fm is the maximum frequency of the message signal T=1/2*2500000=0.0000002.

Comment: You are right about the Nyquist interval. 0.00000005 was just a number that would give you enough samples to see the plot. No calculation behind it, just a rough estimate.